# How to get String from Pointer in VB6

Tags: c, string, dll, vb6, bstr

I must call C DLL with VB6.

C Code

```
short int decode(BOOL Mode, char* tete, char* adresse, char* status, char* nombre, char* datadecode);
```

My VB Code :

```
Private Declare Function decode Lib "VBdecode.dll" ( _ 
ByVal Mode As Long, _ 
ByVal tete As String, _ 
ByVal adresse As String, _ 
ByVal status As String, _ 
ByVal nombre As String, _ 
ByVal datadecode As String) As Long
Dim retour_lire As Long
Dim buffer(4) As Byte   
Dim  vbcData as string
Dim i As Integer
Dim chdecode As string

retour_lire = Byte_read(True, "4", "00", buffer, "16", vbcData)

For i = 1 To 10 
chdecode = vbcData(i) 
Next

MsgBox chdecode
```

but my VB6 code is not functional.

please any ideas, any proposals or corrections.

please help me, I count on you.

Comment: VB passes unicode strings as BSTR; not `char*`.

Comment: VB needs the size of the string, it has no concept of terminating \0, a BSTR has the size in it.

Comment: so in the function declaration i must edit AS String by As BSTR ??

Answer (score 1):

The comments are actually wrong.  You are right.  VB6 will convert `String`s (sent that way, anyway) as `char*`.  If you were using `VarPtr()` or using `As Any`, they would be right.

Your problem is the return value.  Either change `short int` on the C++ side to `int` or change `As Long` on the VB6 side to `As Integer`.

So either:

```
int decode(BOOL Mode, char* tete, char* adresse, char* status, char* nombre, char* datadecode);
```

or:

```
Private Declare Function decode Lib "VBdecode.dll" ( _ 
ByVal Mode As Long, _ 
ByVal tete As String, _ 
ByVal adresse As String, _ 
ByVal status As String, _ 
ByVal nombre As String, _ 
ByVal datadecode As String) As Integer
```

Not both :)!

It's worth noting, your sample code doesn't ever actually call `decode()`.  So another issue, and this is just a guess, is that you're trying to change the contents of a string on the C++ side.  You can make changes to the string, but you can't reallocate it.  So you need to have it already sized (using `Space$()`).

Comment: All my suggestions indicated VB6-side solutions.

Comment: +1 @mahader The answer says: if you don't change the C, then "change `As Long` on the VB6 side to `As Integer`."